# datastore AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcloud

From here: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/datastore-api.html

```
from gcloud import datastore
datastore.set_defaults()
```

Nets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
This happens in Windows 7 and GCE standard setup.  

$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.31
bq 2.0.18
bq-win 2.0.17
compute 2014.09.09
core 2014.09.02
core-win 2014.06.03
dns 2014.09.02
gae-java 1.9.10
gae-java-win 1.9.3
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-win 1.16.0
gsutil 4.5
gsutil-win 3.42
sql 2014.09.02
windows-ssh-tools 2014.07.15
```

Seems as if the wrong version of gcloud.datastore is being called.

Comment: can you run `pip list` to show the gcloud library? The gcloud command you're using is for the SDK command line tools (yeah, its confusing)

Comment: Thanks.  gcloud (0.3.0)  I'm guessing there's a way to go to older versions.

Answer (score 1):

I spun up a compute instance to try this package and had the same issue actually. Its expected though.

The latest version of gcloud (the PyPI package) is 0.3.0 at the time of this writing. If you take a look at the [diff between the release tag and master](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/compare/0.3.0...master) and check the files changed. It becomes apparent that master has a lot of API changes since the last package, including the function you're trying to call.

You probably need to checkout [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) from source and install it that way to use the newer API features.

Comment: Correct and thanks, I ran a git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python.git then ran python setup.py install and was fine.